# How to Recover a gone OSX (mavericks) on MacBookPro?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, time-machine, backup, disk-utility

I shutdown my computer for some reasons with power button (cold shutdown). Unfortunately, my OS i.e.,`mavericks`is gone at the moment and I have no backup from the Data and settings of that Hard drive partition.
  I have the mavericks installation DVD, and tried to repair the disk with `Disk Utility` but it didn't work. getting the following message:

> Disk utility stopped repairing 'Macintosh HD`, Disk utility cant
>   repair the disk, back up as many of your files.....'

I have 2 partitions on my hard drive including `Macintosh HD` which my OS was installed there, and `Mac Store` that contains my own data.
I tried to reinstall and recover the OS on the same drive i.e,`Macintosh HD` in order to keep the settings (password, usernames,) and information of my hard drive (However,later I should do the clean install).   To do this, I selected the `Macintosh HD` disk, and clicked on install , but I am getting an error saying

> The content of disk can't be changed. OSX couldn't be installed on
>   this disk.

So I wanted to ask

**1.** Is there anyway to get my previous OS to work (I need my passwords and Data in Desktop,documents and download folders)?

**2.** Even if 1 is not possible, how can I backup the Data of that partition i.e,`Macintosh HD`?

**3.** Is it possible to extract my saved passwords on Firefox as well?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You really should have stopped at the first error. Remove the drive, put it in a USB enclosure. Install a new drive to the Macbook. Set up fresh install, add recovery tools, plug in the old drive - **then** you're in a position to start trying to rescue the old drive, without making things worse.

Comment: is there any way to use a USB portable OS and boot from that to back up my hard drive?  @Tetsujin

Comment: You'll need a second drive to recover to anyway, so you gain nothing by booting from USB. You need to avoid any process that will try to write to the damaged drive.

Comment: I have an External USB hard drive which is half empty. does it work? @Tetsujin

Comment: If you can boot to a full OS & recovery tools. You'd still be safer with the damaged drive out of the machine until you're ready to examine it.

Comment: please suggest easier ways, I don't want to remove it from laptop. I had same issue 2 years ago. But at that time my data was not so important , so I formatted the disk and clean installed the OS. it would be great if I could attach my USB external drive and backup my HD with a virtual OS @Tetsujin

Comment: You've already hammered at the drive far too much for a simple fix. It's your choice now, depending on how valuable your data is. Try installing an OS & recovery tools on the external, but stop trying to write to the internal until you can access it safely

Answer (score 1):

Problem has been solved, Just thought it may be useful for others.

*1. Is there anyway to get my previous OS to work (I need my passwords and Data in Desktop,documents and download folders)?*

> Maybe, But I don't know yet. But anyway, it is better to clean install
>   the OS again to make your computer faster.

*2. Even if 1 is not possible, how can I backup the Data of that partition i.e,Macintosh HD?*

> Yes, basically I installed mavericks on a USB thumb drive. Next I log
>   in my new OS and copied everything I needed to a external Hard drive.
>   Then I formatted the whole MAC HDD and then clean installed the OS
>   there. Now it is working well.

*3. Is it possible to extract my saved passwords on Firefox as well?*

> Yes, Once I installed the Mavericks on a thumb drive, I went to user
>   folder, library/application support and then found Firefox folder and
>   copied my profile . After I inistalled the OS on MAC HDD, I installed
>   firefox and then pasted that profile in the same place. All of my
>   passwords and bookmarks are there.